# how to make firefox cursor be based on line-height, rather than height of textbox

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

[image]

As shown in the picture above, if you have a textbox with padding, the initial cursor size at least on my Mac is the full specified height with padding. Of course, when you start typing, it goes back to normal text sizes (see that 'Password' watermark).

Is there a way to make the initial cursor the right size, aside from simply resizing the actual textbox? (It works on Webkit browsers fine.)

Example:

```
<input type="textbox" style="height: 40px" />
```

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo work's fix didn't work for me. But here's how mozilla does it on their website (not a fix) : http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/home They just wrap it in a span and add padding.

```
<span class="wrap">
    <input type="text" required="required" placeholder="Search Firefox Help" name="q" class="text">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation (in Firefox), I found that the only way is to manually set the padding. If it's set to auto or left undefined, then it will create an over-sized cursor. As you stated, this behavior is not present in webkit-based browsers. This is most likely a Firefox bug.

Unideal fix:

```
<input type="textbox" style="height: 40px; padding: 10px 0;" />
```